# RxJava buffer/window until element suffers condition

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to read lines from a reader and group them to blocks that belong together.

Source text:

```
bla1
bla2
### block separator ###
bla3
bla4
### block separator ###
...
```

I need to get the two blocks (bla1, bla2) and (bla3, bla4).

Code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import rx.Observable;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BlockBuilder {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("/path/to/some/file");
      LineIterable lineIterable = new LineIterable(fileReader);

      Observable.from(lineIterable)
          .buffer(100)
          // Needed instead of time/count: until line matches condition
          // something like .buffer(line -> line.equals("### block separator ###")
          .forEach(gatheredLines -> {
            String gatheredBlock = StringUtils.join(gatheredLines, '\n');
            System.out.println(gatheredBlock);
            System.out.println("###### ###### ###### ######");
          });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static class LineIterable implements Iterable<String> {
    private final Iterator<String> iterator;
    public LineIterable(Reader reader) {
      iterator = new BufferedReader(reader).lines().iterator();
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      return iterator;
    }
  } 
}
```

It doesn't matter if buffer or window is used or if I'm completely wrong for thinking of those two.

I thought it must be possible with the **bufferClosingSelector** for the buffer or the **closingSelector** for the window.
Both are functions that create an Observer which can trigger the closing of the current buffer or window but I can't see where I can get hold of the current line here.

Answer (score 3):

You can publish your source and use it for both buffering and buffer boundary:

```
Observable<String> source = Observable.just(
        "a", "b", "#", 
        "c", "d", "e", "#", 
        "f", "g");

source.publish(p -> 
        p.filter(v -> !"#".equals(v))
        .buffer(() -> p.filter(v -> "#".equals(v))))
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: That would be great and it compiles with no error. But as soon as I try this code I get a huge error: Error:(16, 25) java: no suitable method found for buffer(()->p.filt[...]s(v)))
    method rx.Observable.<TClosing>buffer(rx.functions.Func0<? extends rx.Observable<? extends TClosing>>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) TClosing
        (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
          rx.Observable<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to ? extends rx.Observable<? extends TClosing>))
[...]

Comment: Works for me from Eclipse 4.5. You may need to add explicit `<String>` before the second `p.filter()` call.

Comment: Can someone explain what is the use of `publish()` in this scenario?

Comment: The signals of the source must be multicast to multiple sub-flows without subscribing to the source multiple times (which is not guaranteed to emit the same data).