# RxJava Observable buffer based on content

Tags: rx-java, observable

I started a project using vertX and RxJava, and I have a problem for which I don't find a solution.

I have an Observable that emits WebSocketFrame for incoming communications,
each WebSocketFrame is composed of a payload (a ByteBuffer) and flags that indicates wether it is the first frame of the message or the last.

I want to make an operation on this Observable to transform it to an Observable that emits ByteBufferd that contain all the frame of a each message.

I tried the `buffer` method but it seems to be designed to regroup items by an arbitrary criteria (time or another observable).

Another way seems to use `compose` to subscribe to the WebSocketFrame observable, to add to buffer on non-ending frame, and to "feed" the ByteBuffer Observable on ending frame. But I don't know how to create and feed a buffer manually.

So if someone has already seen this issue (which IMHO seems pretty common) and have enough knowledge of RxJava for proposing an implementation I would be most gratefull.

thank you for reading.

Comment: Related (in case you need to keep track of state, i.e., buffer based on content spanning multiple emitted items): [RxJava buffer/window with custom counting criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52791691/590790)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to use the [`buffer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer(rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func1)) operator for this (maybe you could do with the simpler [`buffer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer(rx.functions.Func0)), but I'm not sure about that). See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314345/rxjava-buffer-window-until-element-suffers-condition) that covers roughly the same topic and [this GitHub page](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%203%20-%20Taming%20the%20sequence/5.%20Time-shifted%20sequences.md) for more discussion. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Very good answer, I have implemented most of the functionnality, but I still have a problem. the closingObservable get notified first by the publisher, while I need the item to be added before the buffer emits (I cannot wait the next frame to emit the previous message)

Comment: After much try, I found a solution. The problem come from buffer which subscribe on the closing observable before subscribing from the producer. My solution is to chain `.delaySubscription(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)` to the closing observable to force subscription after, and hence receive the notification after.