# RxJava buffer/window with custom counting criteria

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an Observable which is emitting a number of objects and I want to group these objects using the `window` or `buffer` operations. However, instead of specifying a `count` parameter for determining how many objects should be in window I want to be able to use a custom criteria.

For example suppose the observable is emitting instances of a `Message` class like below.

```
class Message(
   val int size: Int
)
```

I would like to buffer or window the message instances based on their `size` variable not just their counts. For example, to gain windows of messages with a total size of at most 5000.

```
// Something like this
readMessages()
    .buffer({ message -> message.size }, 5000)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Related: [RxJava Observable buffer based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38308160/590790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I have to confess, that I'm not a RxJava expert. 
I just found your question challenging and tried to find a solution.

There is a `window()` function with a parameter `boundaryIndicator`. You have to create a `Publisher`/ `Flowable` that emits an item, if the window size is reached.

In the example I created an object `windowManager` that is used as the `boundaryIndicator`. In the `onNext` callback I invoke the `windowManager` and give it a chance to open a new window.

```
val windowManager = object {
    lateinit var emitter: FlowableEmitter<Unit>
    var windowSize: Long = 0

    fun createEmitter(emitter: FlowableEmitter<Unit>) {
        this.emitter = emitter
    }

    fun openWindowIfRequired(size: Long) {
        windowSize += size
        if (windowSize > 5) {
            windowSize = 0
            emitter.onNext(Unit)
        }
    }
}

val windowBoundary = Flowable.create<Unit>(windowManager::createEmitter, BackpressureStrategy.ERROR)

Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).window(windowBoundary).subscribe {
    it.doOnNext {
        windowManager.openWindowIfRequired(it)
    }.doOnSubscribe {
        println("Open window")
    }.doOnComplete {
        println("Close window")
    }.subscribe {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a pretty common scenario (in my case I was aggregating incoming bluetooth packets), but the documentation does not provide much guidance on how to handle this. Perhaps it makes sense to turn this into a dedicated Rx method, ... somehow. As a sidenote, I had to rely on `doAfterNext` since I wanted the emitted item which triggered a new window to be included in the window.